# Ruby array pattern matching

Tags: ruby, haskell, functional-programming

I am new to programming in Ruby and have seen that it has some functional capabilities. Was wondering if there is a way to pattern match on arrays; I am looking to accomplish the following:

```
split_string = str.split("_", 2)
fst = repo_branch_split.first
snd = repo_branch_split.second
```

in a Haskell-like manner:

```
split_string@(fst : snd) = str.split("_", 2)
```

Is there anything similar in ruby or not?

Comment: FYI this is generally (in the language-agnostic sense) referred to as destructuring or destructuring bind, not pattern matching. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node252.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a parallel assignment in Ruby. You can assign an array to variables this way:

```
fst, snd = str.split("_", 2)
```

You can also achieve head / tail behavior from Haskell by assigning rest of the array to a single variable:

```
head, *tail = "foo_bar_baz".split("_")
# head => "foo"
# tail => ["bar", "baz"]
```

Without star in `tail`, it would assign only `bar` string and `baz` would "disappear".

Comment: This is the only answer here so far, that answers the question as it stated and sheds a light on the difference between “parallel assignment” and “pattern matching.” BTW, the Haskell snippet in the OP is not a pattern matching example in the strict meaning.

Comment: It _is_ very interesting. Now we just need the case/matching behavior in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

@smefju's answer is nice but I'll just share a way that you can do even more **destructuring assignment** using ruby

```
def foo &f
  # watch the array get destructured in the block below
  f.call [1,2,3,4,5], :sweet, :candy
end

# first block param is array, so we can destructure it if you want
foo do |(x,*xs),y,z|
  puts %Q{
    x: #{x}
    xs: #{xs}
    y: #{y}
    z: #{z}
  }
end
```

Output

```
x: 1
xs: [2, 3, 4, 5]
y: sweet
z: candy
```

---

This is useful in all sorts of ways

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
hash.reduce({}) do |acc,(k,v)|
  puts %Q{
    acc: #{acc}
    k: #{k}
    v: #{v}
  }
  acc.merge(k => v * v)
end
```

Output

```
acc: {}
k: a
v: 1

acc: {:a=>1}
k: b
v: 2

acc: {:a=>1, :b=>4}
k: c
v: 3

=> {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>9}
```

Aside from destructuring arrays tho, Ruby is pretty lacking in this department. You don't get true hash destructuring and there's no such thing as actual **pattern matching** in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same. Try

```
fst, snd = str.split("_", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow assignment, which uses pattern matching of Ruby 3.

```
'foo_bar_baz'.split('_') => [head, *tail]
```

You would have made the following assignment after the line above.

`head` is `'foo'`

`tail` is `['bar', 'baz']`